# Can I have two processors on the same cd_deployer_conf.xml?

Tags: content-delivery, configuration, deployer-extension

I need to have a PageDeploy Deployer Extension which runs on post-transaction phase, and other extenstions that should be on pre-transaction phase.

Is there any any of doing that in the same cd_deployer_conf?
Can I have two processors elements in there or the only way is to extend a Module? (which I don't want since I'm extending Page and ComponentPresentation and don't want to create a Module and ask if it's Page or ComponentPresentation, I don't want to take that responsibility when it's being already resolved extending PageDeploy for example.

I'm using 8.1.1 version.
Thanks in advance. Guillermo.

**Update**

I'm trying this

```
       <Processor Action="Deploy" Class="com.tridion.deployer.Processor">
            <Module Type="PageDeploy" Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.PageDeploy">
                <Transformer Class="com.tridion.deployer.TCDLTransformer"/>
            </Module>

            <Module Type="ComponentPresentationDeploy" Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.ComponentPresentationDeploy">
                 <Transformer Class="com.tridion.deployer.TCDLTransformer"/>
            </Module>
      </Processor>

      <Processor Action="Deploy" Class="com.tridion.deployer.Processor" Phase="post-transaction"> 

          <Module Type="PageDeploy" Class="extensions.PageDeployExtensionModule">
                <Transformer Class="com.tridion.deployer.TCDLTransformer"/>
          </Module>

          <Module Type="ComponentPresentationDeploy" Class="extensions.ComponentPresentationDeployExtensionModule">
                <Transformer Class="com.tridion.deployer.TCDLTransformer"/>
          </Module>
      </Processor>
```

Should that run everything in the first processor and then, after commiting to the database, everything in the second processor?

**Note the Phase="post-transaction" in the second processor.**

Comment: Can you add your version of Tridion? There are changes in 8.5, that's why I'm asking

Comment: 8.1.1 version. I saw an example with two processors, does that means that first one processor will be picked up and processed and then the second one? –

Answer (score 1):

Having 2 `Processor` elements in 8.1 is totally valid. The one with the `phase="post-transaction"` will execute after the one without such an attribute. Example of such a scenario is when using SmartTarget.